# Put UITextView underneath undefined number of UITableViewCell's?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I will have a number of cells (typically 5-6), and I want a text view underneath it. But I want the position of the text view to change based on the y-value of the lowest cell.

That way, no matter how many cells, the text view will be directly under the cells.

I tried placing the textview within the tableview, but it hid the cells.

Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could for example set it as the `tableFooterView`...

(see https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614976-tablefooterview)